# Use php to update my wordpres's .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to add new dynamic roles in my wordpress's .htaccess

I just do it using the following script:

```php
$f = fopen(".htaccess", "a+");
fwrite($f, "your content");
fclose($f);
```

...but I need to write before the WP comments:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
Wp roles...
# END WordPress
```

is is possibile, by PHP to write in a specific section of my .htaccess?

Comment: why are you adding roles to the htaccess? o.O

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flush_rules` [(codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules). 
A hard flush will actually rewrite the `.htaccess`.

You can combine it together with `add_rewrite_rule()` [(codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), and generally all the [Rewrite_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).

I would not recommend to use your own function to do that, and it is also not recommended to call this function on each load - it can greatly reduce performance.